# storing data retrieved from REST api into variables in python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

So I'm trying to learn more about APIs and the different ways I can use them. Say that as of right now I have

```
import requests, json, pprint

r = requests.get("values from api") 

pprint.pprint(r.json())
```

which returns to me the following

```
> {'currentResultCount': '10',  
> 'results': [{'Name': 'Item_One',
>               'Price': '464086'},
>              {'Name': 'Item_Two',
>               'Price': '70874',
>                and so on.........
```

If I want to store all the price in an array and do some data analysis on them (like find the mean, median, and mode), what should I do?

I tried calling r[0] to see if it's functional or not, but apparantly r is an response object type, so r[0] doesn't work. This is my first time learning about API and data manipulation, any suggestions and learning tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are already doing it by `r.json()`

Comment: sorry but I havn't really looked into what exactly json is yet, but it does seem like json will answer my question. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=json#requests.Response.json) parses JSON response under the hood and returns you a Python data structure, in your case, a regular [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
data = r.json()
```

To get the list of prices, iterate over the `results` values and get the `Price` on every iteration:

```
prices = [item['Price'] for item in data['results']]
```

You may also cast prices to [`float`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int):

```
prices = [float(item['Price']) for item in data['results']]
```

Comment: I am using 

                                `res = conn.getresponse()
                                data = res.read()
                                print(data.decode("utf-8"))
                                mydata = data.json()`

But what I get is, `RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response` What should be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Here `r` is `Response` type object which contains a server's response to an HTTP request. Now in your code you are using,

```
r = requests.get("values from api")
```

`get` method must receive a `url` as parameter.

You can use `dir(r)` to see the properties of the object. You can try some of them. If there is a json-encoded content of a response, `r.json()` will return it. Now `json` is very much similar to python `dictionary`. So you can use this as a dictionary, store it in a list and also manipulate the data.